# MSChart on ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mschart

I upgraded my MVC Application using MSChart to MVC 2 and have ended up with broken image links for the charts.

I get no build errors anymore, and have completed the following steps.

First, I setup the following web.config lines.

```
add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" 
assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
```

and

```
add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" 
type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, 
System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"
```

(NOTE:  I took the chevrons off so the lines would appear)

The next thing I did was create this page with the following code.  Which should, according to it working in MVC<1, showed 4 charts.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Scorecard.Views" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Scorecard
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="applicationTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderApplicationName" runat="server">
    <%=Html.Encode(ViewData["ApplicationTitle"])%>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<h2>
    Web Analysis Scorecard
</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%
                ChartHelper chartHelper = new ChartHelper("Top Countries",
                                                          (double[])ViewData["TopCountryCounts"],
                                                          (string[])ViewData["TopCountries"],
                                                        SeriesChartType.Pie);
                Chart chartPieTwo = chartHelper.ResultingChart;

                // Explode data point with label "USA"
                chartPieTwo.Series["DefaultSeries"].Points[3]["Exploded"] = "true";

                chartHelper.RenderChart(this);
            %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%
                chartHelper = new ChartHelper("View Cart Trend",
                                              (double[])ViewData["LineValues"],
                                              (string[])ViewData["TopEngines"],
                                              SeriesChartType.Line);
                chartHelper.RenderChart(this);
            %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%  chartHelper = new ChartHelper("Yesterday's Page Views",
                          (double[])ViewData["ColumnStats"],
                          (string[])ViewData["ColumnStatHeaders"],
                          SeriesChartType.Column);
                chartHelper.RenderChart(this);
            %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%
                double[] theValues = (double[])ViewData["ColumnStats"];
                double[] newValues = new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
                int count = 0;
                int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
                foreach (double d in theValues)
                {
                    newValues[count] += d * daysInMonth;
                    count++;
                }

                chartHelper = new ChartHelper("Current Month Page Views",
                                              newValues,
                                              (string[])ViewData["ColumnStatHeaders"],
                                              SeriesChartType.Bar);
                chartHelper.RenderChart(this);
            %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I also posted a blog entry here: http://blog.adronbhall.com/post/2010/04/12/MVC-2-Breaks-my-Charts.aspx

Comment: Some of the HTML got messed up in the posting.  But the core components are there for the page.  Please do check my blog post to see an image of the page if curious.

Comment: It's a good idea if you actually post your entire blog post as a question here. Having an external dependency on a question is never a 'good thing'.